# How to link the nether portals in 1.15.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am going to blow my mind if there is no person ho can explain how it works:

In overworld i have 2 portals:
(OW1): -149  55  -199
(OW2): 60  30  -484

In nether i have 2 portals:
(N1): -18  38  -26
(N2): 7  127+  -60

But, as those portals seems far away from each other i was thinking that they are connected as followed:

- OW1<->N1
- OW2<->N2

But they connected in line

- OW1<->N1<-OW2<-N2

Can someone explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When connecting two portals, as you are aware, the X and Z values should be divided by 8 on the Nether side.  The Y value, however should stay the same.

Also, when talking about portals 'connecting', there is no such thing.  The calculation is done EVERY time you step through a portal.  Minecraft will work out the co-ordinates where it expects a portal to be, and then begins searching for the nearest one to those exact co-ordinates.

As such, your 'Overworld 2' portal is at Y=30.  In the nether, it looks for the portal closest to 7 30 -60, using simple Pythagoras: √(xdiff² + ydiff² + zdiff²)

N1 is √(25² + 8² + 34²), or about 43 blocks away.
N2 is √(97²) - which is obviously 97 blocks away.

N1 is closer, so that's where you come out.

To fix this, you should add another portal at y=30, maybe with stairs/ladder up to the higher one.  Alternatively, build your overworld portal *above* y=84ish.